# SPF passes but in Gmail, 'Show Original', top section doesn't show SPF: PASS with IP

Tags: email, gmail, spf

When I send an email from my HostGator account to my Gmail account, I see in the header `spf=pass...`

When I paste the header in this tool -> https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/

It shows `SPF: pass` with IP 162.241.136.65 and no errors.

But in Gmail when I click on the email and then "Show Original", the top section does not show any reference to `SPF: PASS` with IP... Just `DKIM: 'PASS'`.

All other emails I receive (except from my host) shows `SPF: PASS`. My txt record is `v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:162.241.136.65 -all`.

Is this something I need to be concerned with or is there a fix?

I sent an email to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` as was requested and this is the return:

```
Summary of Results
SPF check:          pass
"iprev" check:      pass
DKIM check:         pass
DKIM check:         pass

Details:
HELO hostname:  pro.proscan.org
Source IP:      162.241.136.65
mail-from:      ____@proscan.org
SPF check details:
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=____@proscan.org

DNS record(s):
    proscan.org. 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:162.241.136.65 -all"
    proscan.org. 300 IN MX 0 proscan.org.
    proscan.org. 300 IN A 162.241.136.65
"iprev" check details:
Result:         pass (matches pro.proscan.org)
ID(s) verified: policy.iprev=162.241.136.65
DNS record(s):
    65.136.241.162.in-addr.arpa. 300 IN PTR pro.proscan.org.
    pro.proscan.org. 300 IN A 162.241.136.65
DKIM check details:
Result:         pass (matches From: ____@proscan.org)
ID(s) verified: header.d=proscan.org
```

This link to the image shows what I'm talking about.
[Missing SPF](https://proscan.org/SPF%20Missing.png)

Comment: Please send an email from your HostGator account to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. You will receive a report back showing information about your SPF configuration. Then, please edit the your question to append the report.  Someone on here will be able to guide you to a solution, with the help of the results of this test.

Comment: gmail adds an `Authentication-Results` header which contain information for dkim, spf and dmarc if appropriate. You should look at this header to get the information. The tool you use just interprets the header for you, but if you insist on viewing the original mail header then you have to do the interpretation yourself and for this you need to understand the header. For more information about this header see [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8601).

Comment: Everything looks good with your SPF setup, according to the results that you posted from port25.com.  As to why you are not seeing any info in the headers of the messages that you sent to your Gmail address - by any chance, do you have an Gmail inbound gateway setup?  See https://support.google.com/a/answer/60730?hl=en for more info (see where it reads, 'Gmail doesn't do SPF or DMARC checks on incoming messages from the IP addresses you specify in the setting').  Also:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242104/spf-dmarc-for-shared-email-provider-gmail-how-did-this-email-pass-spf

Comment: Folks, I'm going to give up on this. I tried everything on the HostGator side and the Gmail side. dkim, spf, & dmarc all shows pass. I see my domain is on the UCEPROTECT blacklist. I use my HostGator account to send out keys to my software so I don't get replies back. So perhaps Gmail is checking that blacklist or emails that don't get replies back. Thank you everyone for your help.